# Querydsl generates invalid SQL on basic aggregate query

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, querydsl

I am using QueryDSL and Hibernate to query a SqlServer2008 database.

I have a Sessions table that contains a sessionId column. I want to obtain the max sessionId.

I run the following query:

```
QSessions session = QSessions.sessions;
HibernateSQLQuery query = new HibernateSQLQuery(sessionFactory.openSession(), new SQLServer2005Templates());
query.from(session).list(session.sessionId.max());
```

My hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://SVR;databaseName=DB</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">X</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">X</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect</property>

        <mapping class="com.coveo.data.Sessions" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

When I run the query, I can see that Hibernate attempts to run the following SQL query:

```
17:36:10.011 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select max(sessions.*.sessionId) as col__1 from sessions
```

This is not valid SQL. I would have expected

```
select max(sessions.sessionId) as col__1 from sessions
```

When Hibernate attempts to execute the query, I get the following error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '*'.
```

I get the same syntax error when attempting to run the invalid SQL query using SQL Management Studio.

Why does Querydsl require a dialect? Isn't Hibernate in charge of generating the SQL?

**Why is the generated SQL invalid?**

EDIT: I get the same behavior when using .avg(), .min() or another aggregate function.

Comment: Have you talked with [querydsl support / forums](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/querydsl) etc.? I'm not sure how many people here are familiar with querydsl, never mind will be able to tell you why it works this way.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: At least as many as 21, I guess.

Comment: @AndriyM I guess I didn't make my point clearly. I didn't expect the number to be 0, but how many are online right now, watching the tag, etc.? I'd start with the support forum.

Comment: I've followed your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues here.

- You use `HibernateSQLQuery` which is meant to execute SQL queries through the Hibernate API, please use `HibernateQuery` for Hibernate ORM queries
- You use the Q-type generated for ORM queries in SQL queries. Querydsl should handle this usage better and I created a ticket for it https://github.com/mysema/querydsl/issues/463

Querydsl supports both ORM and SQL based queries for Hibernate and you accidently mixed them.

For normal Hibernate queries your example would be

```
QSessions session = QSessions.sessions;
HibernateQuery query = new HibernateQuery(sessionFactory.openSession());
query.from(session).list(session.sessionId.max());
```

I assume that QSessions is based on the Sessions entity.

jOOQ is a very good alternative for the SQL level, but if you need to access also JPA and NoSQL based storages, Querydsl offers more.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up switching to [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org).
So far, the experience has been very positive. The API is somewhat similar, the documentation is better and it doesn't generate invalid SQL.